# Hashmap with string array as value in C

Tags: c, database, hashmap, tuples, hashtable

I am building a program in C that reads a database file and translates it into some C structures.

Is it possible to implement a hash table that uses an int as the key and returns a string array (char **) as the value (This is to retrieve a certain tuple in the database by id).

Thanks!

Comment: are asking how to implement an SQL database in C ? just use solutions that are already available like http://sqlite.org/

Comment: "Is it possible to implement a hash table that uses an int as the key and returns a string array (char **) as the value" - nothing is impossible in software.

Comment: (voted down and for closure becuse this is a "write code for me" non-question.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. But it really depends on the nature of the key. If you can't find a pattern of how a key maps to a value, it is very difficult to implement a hash function. One approach would be to implement a height balanced binary search tree with respect to the keys and storing the values as well. This would guarantee worst case time complexity of O(logn) for every operation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, here an example using SuperFastHash (comments in code):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct data {
    int index;
    char name[16];
    struct data *next;
} data;

extern char *strdup(const char *);

#define get16bits(d) ((((uint32_t)(((const uint8_t *)(d))[1])) << 8)\
                       +(uint32_t)(((const uint8_t *)(d))[0]))

uint32_t SuperFastHash(const char * data, int len)
{
    uint32_t hash = len, tmp;
    int rem;

    if (len <= 0 || data == NULL) return 0;

    rem = len & 3;
    len >>= 2;

    /* Main loop */
    for (;len > 0; len--) {
        hash  += (get16bits(data));
        tmp    = (get16bits(data + 2) << 11) ^ hash;
        hash   = (hash << 16) ^ tmp;
        data  += 2 * sizeof(uint16_t);
        hash  += hash >> 11;
    }

    /* Handle end cases */
    switch (rem) {
        case 3:
            hash += get16bits(data);
            hash ^= hash << 16;
            hash ^= ((signed char)data[sizeof(uint16_t)]) << 18;
            hash += hash >> 11;
            break;
        case 2:
            hash += get16bits(data);
            hash ^= hash << 11;
            hash += hash >> 17;
            break;
        case 1:
            hash += (signed char)*data;
            hash ^= hash << 10;
            hash += hash >> 1;
    }

    /* Force "avalanching" of final 127 bits */
    hash ^= hash << 3;
    hash += hash >> 5;
    hash ^= hash << 4;
    hash += hash >> 17;
    hash ^= hash << 25;
    hash += hash >> 6;

    return hash;
}

/* return data (or NULL if exists) */
data *insert(data **table, data *value, size_t n)
{
    uint32_t hash;
    data *temp;
    char s[10];
    int len;

    /* convert index to string */
    len = sprintf(s, "%d", value->index);
    hash = SuperFastHash(s, len) % n;
    if (table[hash] == NULL) {
        /* not found, insert */
        table[hash] = value;
    } else {
        temp = table[hash];
        while (1) {
            if (temp == value) return NULL;
            if (temp->next) {
                temp = temp->next;
            } else break;
        }
        /* not found, insert */
        temp->next = value;
    }
    return value;
}

/* return data as array of strings (or NULL if not found) */
char **search(data **table, int index, size_t n)
{
    char **record;
    uint32_t hash;
    data *temp;
    char s[10];
    int len;

    /* convert index to string */
    len = sprintf(s, "%d", index);
    hash = SuperFastHash(s, len) % n;
    if (table[hash] != NULL) {
        temp = table[hash];
        while (temp) {
            if (temp->index == index) {
                /* struct to array of strings (check mallocs) */
                record = malloc(sizeof(*record) * 2);
                record[0] = strdup(s);
                record[1] = strdup(temp->name);
                return record;
            }
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }
    /* not found */
    return NULL;
}

void free_record(char **record)
{
    free(record[0]);
    free(record[1]);
    free(record);
}

int main(void)
{
    data values[] = {
        {4611, "Kessie", NULL},
        {5141, "Neville", NULL},
        {6484, "Dominic", NULL},
        {2074, "Kelly", NULL},
        {9969, "Petra", NULL},
        {9663, "Laura", NULL},
        {6136, "Bianca", NULL},
        {1647, "Aurelia", NULL},
        {8512, "Britanney", NULL},
        {2613, "Oprah", NULL},
        {2610, "Shay", NULL},
        {6591, "Ralph", NULL},
        {9302, "Charity", NULL},
        {2593, "Lillian", NULL},
        {9732, "Hop", NULL}
    };
    size_t i, n = sizeof(values) / sizeof(values[0]);
    /* array of pointers to values */
    data **table = calloc(n, sizeof(*table));
    /* value as array of strings */
    char **record;

    if (table == NULL) {
        perror("calloc");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    puts("Inserting ...");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d %s\n", values[i].index, values[i].name);
        insert(table, &values[i], n);
    }
    if (!insert(table, &values[1], n)) puts("Exists");
    puts("Searching ...");
    for (i = 2610; i < 2615; i++) {
        record = search(table, i, n);
        if (record == NULL) {
            printf("%zu Not found\n", i);
        } else {
            printf("%s %s\n", record[0], record[1]);
            free_record(record);
        }
    }
    free(table);
    return 0;
}
```

But as pointed out by Rikayan, a balanced binary search tree is a best option.